# Rhomobile app not working if 3G network proxy is active

Tags: android, ios, proxy, rhomobile, rhodes

If my phone 3g network use proxy, rhomobile app is not working. It loads splash screen and after remain stucked to a white screen without response.

Is there a solution/patch for this problem?

Or can I test if proxy is activated and show popup whith some message for user on aplication startup??

I tested on Android and iOS and no success.